# Правка стандартных компонентов в QtQuick

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick

В своей программе я использую связку QtQuick и C++, где первый отвечает за интерфейс, а второй за решение емких задач. Работать приложение должно и на стационарном ПК и на мобильных устройствах(с ограниченным функционалом). Не хочу затягивать монологами, вопрос прост: где лежат исходники этого компонента(Map)? Могу ли я вносить в него изменения и сразу же видеть эти изменения в своем приложении или он жестко зашит в одной из библиотек? Понятное дело, что в исходниках Qt он есть. Но мне хотелось бы подключить его как QML файлы к своему проекту. Начать можно с кастомизации компонента Button или Rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

Кастомизация Rectangle?

Создаете новый файл MyRectangle.qml, внутри пишете что-то подобное, везде используете MyRectangle

```
Rectangle {
    color: "red"
}
```

Если говорить о Qt Quick Controls 2, то кастомизируются они как-то [так](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-customize.html).

С Map ничего поделать без правки исходников нельзя, а что конкретно вы хотели?

Comment: Подставить другие тайлы, работа с растрами сделанными с БПЛА, работа в офлайн режиме.

Comment: @vladislav-buzdin

Comment: Отправилось случайно :/ Так вот, посмотрите на MapBox.

Comment: Не решает проблемы офлайна. А так используется mapbox. Очень важно уметь открывать это все в офлайн и передавать данные с машины на машину через внешние накопители для десктопов. Очень маловероятно что получится это реализовать штатными средствами. mapbox для qt не переваривает windows.

Comment: Для справки. В моем распоряжении огромные фотопланы поверхности земли. Например средний размер одного около 1-2 гб. Это изображение с геопривязкой. Открыть его на машине без интернета не получится.